# Handle iPhone calling from external device (e.g. a car)

Tags: ios, iphone

How does a car's system handle calls from an iPhone? The device is plugged through into the car's system using the dock connector at the bottom of the iPhone. Now when a call comes through the car intercepts it and you can press a button (usually on the steering wheel) to answer and then speak through the inbuilt microphones of the car and listen through the speakers in the car. All of this is done through connecting the device into a dock.... how does this work?

P.S: Is it possible to initiate calls from an outside system as well?

P.P.S: All of this is done without an App being installed on the iPhone itself though...

Comment: Bluetooth is used, not the dock connector.  But this question belongs on [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any bluetooth devices that implement HFP or HSP bluetooth profiles will be able to receive the call from iPhone.To display the info( Caller ID or Contact name) on the car kit, the device has to implement PBAP or MAP bluetooth profiles.No App is required on iPhone.